# Getting HTML Generated By ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I'm trying to build a report screen that takes a while (~30 seconds) to generate due to the data. What I would like to do is get the HTML that's generated by the view and save it to a text file.

Is there a way to get the HTML generated by a View? If so, how? Please note that my .cshtml file includes some RAZOR. I'm not sure if that plays into this equation or not.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why you dont open in browser and save source as to get all html component..Once it is in browser there will be no razor syntax only plain html,css,script.

Comment: What are you intending on doing with this HTML? caching the output? If so, it would probably be better to look at caching the data instead.

Comment: Why do you want to write this to a file? Do what Chris says and look at caching the request

Comment: I think Bill Jones want to export report data not html ...If this is the case it is a bad idea to export using html as asp.net and c# already gives report export support...

Comment: Check out this answer and see if it helps [Render a view as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string).

Comment: @Garry What export support is built into MVC4?

Comment: @Bill Jones did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function to do this sort of thing, usually when I want to create email HTML using razor:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model, ControllerContext context)
{
    context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, context.Controller.ViewData, context.Controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```